# Extra space in the Top of Detail View that won't go away (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an extra space in a detail view that won't go away. The view comes from a NavigationLink but I've tried it with or without a NavigationView. I tried to wrap it replace the ScrollView with the NavigationView but that didn't work. I think a lot of Swift coders have encountered this problem and there's no proper answer out there that worked for me.

This is my DetailView

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
                
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Huge Font Recipe Title")
                .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .bold))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding([.leading, .top, .trailing])
                                            
                    VStack {
                        Image("img1")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 375, height: 375)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                            
                        Spacer()

                            
                        }.padding(.bottom)
                                                        

                    }
                  }
               }
            
}
             
struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailView()
    }
}
```

And this is the Parent view (Content View) which holds the NavigationView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            ScrollView (showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(recipecardData) { item in

                            NavigationLink(
                            destination: DetailView()) {

                            RecipeCards( card: item)
                        }
                    }
                }

                        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Navigation")
                    }
            }
}



            struct RecipeCards: View {

                var card: RecipeCard

                var body: some View {

                    ZStack {
                        Image(card.imageName)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 334, height: 335)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .padding()
                            .shadow(radius: 16)

                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.clear)
                            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .blue]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
            )
                            .frame(width: 334, height: 335)
                           .cornerRadius(10)


                        HStack {

                            Text(card.title)
                                .font(.system(size: 27,weight: .bold))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(minWidth: 10, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))

                            }

                        .padding(.bottom, 268)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 34, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
                    }
                }
            }


            struct RecipeCard: Identifiable {
                var id = UUID()
                var title: String
                var imageName: String

            }

            let recipecardData =  [
            RecipeCard(title: "Title 1", imageName: "img1"),
            RecipeCard(title: "Title 2", imageName: "img2")
            ]


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You have many missing dependencies, please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It is hard to replicate that issue with the above code. Where is RecipeDetail() in your ParentView? What is TabBarView()?

Comment: @pawello2222 This is my first question here, excuse the bad documentation. I fixed the code above. Should work now.

Comment: @davidev I have multiple views, including TabBarView that holds the TabBar and the RecipeList. But I simplified the code above, you should be able to run it now and see the problem. thank you for the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is the `NavigationBar` with a `large` style. You can make it smaller by using this modifier:

```
.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
```

[image: Inline]

---

## Update due to OP's comment

If you want to keep the large title while expanding the contents, you should consider ignoring the safe area's `top` edge:

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

[image: Top]

Also, you may want to add some `padding`s **BEFORE** ignoring safe area to preserve the `inline` navigation size.

[image: Padding]

---

## Important

1. **Note that** all of these modifiers should apply to the destination view.
2. The `NavigationBar` will stay there and prevent touch events from passing to the views below. You should use `.navigationBarHidden(true)` if you really need to get rid of it.

Comment: Hi mojtaba, this solved the spacing problem. thank you! However, I want the user to see the NavigationBarTitle in large. There must be another solution, right?

Comment: Maybe, but that is another question. Why did you accept another one's answer when that is exactly the same as mine but 2 hours later? @Lewis

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I believe OP needed an explanation as well and not only a one-line solution. If I didn't know what you're talking about I'd assume you propose to change the `navigationBarTitle` in the `ContentView`. And there's no need to downvote, I'm just trying to help :)

Comment: thank you @MojtabaHosseini

Answer (score 5):

Use `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)` in your DetailView instead of  `.navigationBarTitle(...)` if no title needed for the detail view.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `displayMode: .inline` to the `NavigationBar` in your `DetailView`:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ...
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Some title", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

In every *step* of navigation you can set a different `NavigationBar` title. By setting a `displayMode` you control its style (and *height*).

Your issue occurred because in your `DetailView` you set a *large* `NavigationBar` title (if you didn't specify it explicitly, its style will be copied from the parent view). Also, you didn't specify its *text* - it was empty.

Which means you didn't have an extra *space* between the NavigationBar and the title of your image. It was an *empty* large NavigationBar title.